# python 403 Not Authorized to access this resource/api

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I have a working implementation of an integration in GoLang with the Go library.

Now I'm trying to convert it to python using the py package: google-api-python-client.

I'm keep getting an error message of unauthorized for the following code:

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

credentials = service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
req = service.users().get(userKey='<admin email>')
req.execute()
```

before the last line i added a breakpoint and looked at the request object and couldn't find anything regarding the credentials (searched in the url, headers, cookies and body).

Comment: There's actually a [Python Quickstart for Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python) that you can base your code on. If you're going to modify scopes, delete the previously saved credentials.

Comment: i already tried this quickstart and the example didn't work without the runflow command.

turns out i was missing a final line of code:
credendials = credendials.create_delegated(delegated_user)